# How to convert this derivation of Poiseuille's law into the standard one?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow

I am trying to derive Poiseuille's law. I have reached a point in the derivation where I have:

$$V=\frac{(p1-p2)(R^2)}{4lu}$$

Where $l$ is length, u is viscosity, p is pressure, v is flow velocity and R is radius.
What I am stuck on is shifting this to the volumetric flow rate:

$$V\pi R^2=Q=\frac{(p1-p2)(R^4)}{4lu}.$$

However this is incorrect as Poiseuille's law is divided by 8. I know that I am probably missing something obvious, but I can't think of a reason as to why the whole equation needs to be halved. Any help understanding why (or whether my original derivation for V was inaccurate) would be appreciated.

Comment: It's hard to know where you might be going wrong without seeing your derivation.

Answer (score 1):

The expression for the flow speed as a function of distance from the pipe center is:

$$V(r)=\frac{(p_1-p_2)(r^2 - R^2)}{4l\mu}$$

The average velocity of the flow can be calculated by performing an integration over the pipe cross section, and then dividing by the cross-sectional area:

$$V_{avg} = \frac{\int_{0}^{R}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{(p_1 - p_2)(r^2 - R^2)}{4l\mu}rd\theta dr}{\pi R^2}$$

The extra factor of $r$ comes from the fact we are doing everything in polar coordinates. Since the function is independent of $\theta$,

$$V_{avg} = \frac{\int_{0}^{R}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{(p_1 - p_2)(r^2 - R^2)}{4l\mu}2\pi rdr}{\pi R^2} = \frac{(p_1-p_2)R^2}{8l\mu}$$

The factor of $8$ comes from the combination of integrating the $r^3$ term, resulting in a $\frac{1}{4}$ term, multiplied by the $2$ from the angular integration, and multiplied again by the original $\frac{1}{4}$ in the $V(r)$ expression to yield a factor of $\frac{1}{8}$.

Comment: This is what I also thought, but when I did integrate the expression over R to add up all the possible velocities, and then divided by $\pi R^2$, I got $\frac{\pi R(p1-p2)}{12lu}$. I am not sure where I am going wrong here.

Comment: I will edit my answer to demonstrate the integration—but consider adding a description of your derivation up to the expressions you obtain in your next question, so that your error (and our answers) become clearer.